# where vs in which

Tags: where, where-which

I found this sentence in a dictionary:

> A nursery is a place where children who are not old enough to go to school are looked after.

I want to know if *in which* can be used instead of *where*.

Comment: Regarding the question, I think you can use *in which* instead of *where*.

Comment: @IBG I don't think it's a duplicate. That question is about whether it's OK to use _where_ for something that isn't a location.

Comment: Yes, this is the opposite situation. The chunk _the/a place in which_ is equivalent to _the/a place where_, since _place_ is a locative. Furthermore, _the/a place where_ is equivalent to _where_, since _where_ can only modify a place. So _A nursery is where ..._ would be grammatical, as well (though not appropriate for a dictionary). Metaphorically, this can expand to any event or thing, considered as a "place" in some metaphor theme. _The Super Bowl is [(the place) where/the place in which/the place] you find the best ads._